# Batch File Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to migrate a bunch of files across several subfolders in a single directory. Each subfolder containing a maximum of 100 data files (0000-0099,0100-0199, etc.) and is named dir_001, dir_002 etc. respectfully.

For example I can successfully transfer *all* the files that begin with a prefix of "F_0" using the following:

```
for /r X:\<PATH1>\ %%F in (F_0*.txt) do copy %%F E:\<PATH2>\
```

This will grab **all** the files from **all** the subfolders covering all images from F_00001.txt to F_09999.txt (or whatever the upper limit is). But most of the time I only need a smaller subset such as from F_04395.txt through F04542.txt.

Here is what I have been trying that does *not* work

```
for /r X:\PATH1\ %%F in (F_0*.txt) do (
    For %%A in (%%F) do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    For /L %%i in (4395 1 4542)do if /I exist Folder\F_0%%i.txt copy %%F E:\PATH2\
    )
)
```

This seems to break when it comes to converting the file path to a variable.

It also would need to work for a sequence from F_000001.txt through F_010001.txt or in other words from file number 1 through 1001 (with a different number of leading zeros for 0-9, 10-99,100-999,1000-9999, so it is always a 5 digit number plus the prefix of "F_0")

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Update:
Thanks for @Gerhard I've changed the code to what is below but still not working and there is an issue combining/concatenating the %%dpA variable with the rest of the filename. The result of the below code is a double slash between the filename and the path, or if I take out the hard coded clash then the code also fails.

```
    for /r X:\PATH1\ %%F in (F_0*.txt) do (
    For %%A in (%%F) do (
    For /L %%i in (4395 1 4542)do if /I exist %%dpA\F_0%%i.txt copy %%F E:\PATH2\
    )
)
```

Comment: Firstly, you are `set`ting a variable and you are never using it. Secondly, even if you did, you cannot `set` and use a variable inside of a code block like this without enabling `delayedexpansion` but you do not need to even set a variable here, you can simply use `%%~dpA` directly.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the code, still not working, a step closer I hope

Comment: The way you are running 3 for loops is creating a lot of overhead for your script as it is processing each for loop's item multiple times in the next loop. why not just run `for /L` loop and iterate the files? for instance: `For /L %%i in (4395,1,4542) do if exist "X:\path\F_0%%i.txt" copy "X:\path\F_0%%i.txt" "E:\PATH2\"`

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard You have been a big help. Final code is above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again to @Gerhard you beat me to the optomization but still helped greatly. Here is my final code that also address the multiple subfolders, and consolidated into a single line!

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (43,1,45,) do ((SET "formattedValue=000000%%i" & SET PathSource2=X:\Path1\Dir_!formattedValue:~-3!) & (For /L %%i in (4395 ,1,4542) do (if exist "!PathSource2!\F_0%%i.jpg" copy "!PathSource2!\F_0%%i.txt" "E:\Path2\")))
```